Auto generating Junit tests tool with usage of AI
I am using IntelliJ and I write my code in Java. I would like to create a bunch of Junit tests, because they are missing. I wonder if there is any tool which is using AI (like ChatGPT) which can generate the Junits tests automaticaly?
